# Design configuration multistore magento 2.1

Tags: multistore, magento-2.1, logo

We set up a multistore site and it works. Now I wanted to change the logo and with 2.1. it moved to **content -> design -> configuration**,

but I can't switch website view and only one of the shops (own website and own store view) show up.

Like in the below picture. How can I change the settings **(pagination, header, logo etc.)** for the other stores?

[image]

Comment: In the version 2.0.* it was really simple to change these settings with the store views under stores-> configuration -> general -> design. Isn't there any other, easier and faster possibility in 2.1 instead creating a new child theme?

Comment: You are correct, I forgot about this because I usually have to do more than change the logo between stores.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution: run 
bin/magento indexer:reindex 
and it will show up

Comment: This worked for me and was exactly what I was after. Apparently design_config_grid is a new index with 2.1 and after reindexing it my new multistore appears on the content > design > configuration page.